# Tikz arrow head not staying on path

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

Consider the following MWE, any suggestions on how to make the arrow head and the path stay on the base path? (in my real application, my circles are not this small, smaller circles show the problem better).

If you un comment the version using `->` you will notice that that particular arrow head does not show this problem.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    tst/.style={
      ultra thick, opacity=0.5,
      dashed
    },
    my-arc/.style={
      start angle=90, end angle=360+90,radius=1
    }
  }

  \draw (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0);
  \draw (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);

  \draw[thin] (0,0) circle (1);
%  \draw[green,tst,->]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];
  \draw[red,tst,-Latex]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];
%  \draw[tst,-Stealth]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add `bending` library.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows.meta,bending}   %%<<----- note here
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \tikzset{
    tst/.style={
      ultra thick, opacity=0.5,
      dashed
    },
    my-arc/.style={
      start angle=90, end angle=360+90,radius=1
    }
  }

  \draw (-1.2,0) -- (1.2,0);
  \draw (0,-1.2) -- (0,1.2);

  \draw[thin] (0,0) circle (1);
%  \draw[green,tst,->]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];
  \draw[red,tst,-Latex]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];
%  \draw[tst,-Stealth]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want more, use bend as the option:

```
\draw[red,tst,-{Latex[bend]}]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];
```

[image]

Or also `flex` or `flex'`:

```
\draw[red,tst,-{Latex[flex'=.75]}]  (0,1) arc [my-arc];
```

[image]

Adjust `flex'` value suitably.